# Flask Deploy on Gunicorn and Nginx Threadsafe error

Tags: python, python-3.x, nginx, flask, gunicorn

i deploy a Flask scrip as below on a Centos7 vps.

```
from flask import Flask, request
import time


# http server
app = Flask(__name__)


server_dict = dict()
server_status_dict = dict()


@app.route('/<ip>')
def report(ip):
    server_dict[ip] = time.time()
    return "ok" + ":"+ip + ":"+str(time.time()) 

@app.route('/check')
def check(): 
    for server in server_dict: 
        difference = time.time()-server_dict[server]
        if difference < 120:
            server_status_dict[server]= "ok" + ":"+str(difference)
        elif difference > 172800:
            del server_status_dict[server]
        else:
            server_status_dict[server]= "fail" + ":"+str(difference)
    message =''
    for item in server_status_dict:
        message =  message+ f'{item}:{server_status_dict[item]}<br>' 
    return message   


# main function
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    # start server
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=1111)
```

I run it in 2 way.
1. direct run the python scrip by type "python3.7 test.py"
2. deploy with Gunicorn and Nginx.

And i make a script to test this Flask api as below

```
import requests

for i in range(100):
    requests.get(f'http://example.org/{i}')

print("done 1")


for i in range(100):
    requests.get(f'http://server_IP:1111/{i}')

print("done 2")
```

with 1st option. The scrip run ok. When i go to "http://server_IP:1111/check". It give 100 entry

```
0:fail:759.2570543289185
1:fail:758.8786942958832
2:fail:758.5069346427917
3:fail:758.1351449489594
4:fail:757.7596881389618
5:fail:757.3863341808319
6:fail:757.010666847229
7:fail:756.6381704807281
8:fail:756.2622804641724
9:fail:755.8862257003784
10:fail:755.5146560668945
11:fail:755.1291973590851
12:fail:754.7365326881409
13:fail:754.356516122818
14:fail:753.981279373169
15:fail:753.6054089069366
16:fail:753.2138450145721
17:fail:752.818380355835
18:fail:752.4382960796356
19:fail:752.0667576789856
20:fail:751.7003827095032
21:fail:751.3132452964783
22:fail:750.9238367080688
23:fail:750.5513446331024
24:fail:750.1771302223206
25:fail:749.7979047298431
26:fail:749.4190459251404
27:fail:749.0481917858124
28:fail:748.6672575473785
29:fail:748.2830848693848
30:fail:747.909416437149
31:fail:747.5357480049133
32:fail:747.1593079566956
33:fail:746.7837409973145
34:fail:746.3994252681732
35:fail:746.0265593528748
36:fail:745.6520500183105
37:fail:745.2793860435486
38:fail:744.904794216156
39:fail:744.5288579463959
40:fail:744.1554877758026
41:fail:743.7802364826202
42:fail:743.4038217067719
43:fail:743.0015366077423
44:fail:742.616055727005
45:fail:742.2241225242615
46:fail:741.8492274284363
47:fail:741.4703538417816
48:fail:741.0822536945343
49:fail:740.7089433670044
50:fail:740.3415608406067
51:fail:739.9651212692261
52:fail:739.5690467357635
53:fail:739.1705968379974
54:fail:738.7934353351593
55:fail:738.4151468276978
56:fail:738.0353343486786
57:fail:737.6413230895996
58:fail:737.2650125026703
59:fail:736.8714530467987
60:fail:736.4966006278992
61:fail:736.1160485744476
62:fail:735.7190825939178
63:fail:735.3462533950806
64:fail:734.9714226722717
65:fail:734.5957586765289
66:fail:734.2199065685272
67:fail:733.8420522212982
68:fail:733.4598708152771
69:fail:733.0775439739227
70:fail:732.6989419460297
71:fail:732.3187139034271
72:fail:731.9392898082733
73:fail:731.5633845329285
74:fail:731.1846008300781
75:fail:730.8096714019775
76:fail:730.4323663711548
77:fail:730.0437717437744
78:fail:729.6707744598389
79:fail:729.2912459373474
80:fail:728.8956272602081
81:fail:728.5194237232208
82:fail:728.1444211006165
83:fail:727.7692551612854
84:fail:727.3844618797302
85:fail:727.0075929164886
86:fail:726.612667798996
87:fail:726.2140853404999
88:fail:725.8366258144379
89:fail:725.4668595790863
90:fail:725.080512046814
91:fail:724.7128283977509
92:fail:724.3402450084686
93:fail:723.9593863487244
94:fail:723.5851843357086
95:fail:723.2059574127197
96:fail:722.802404165268
97:fail:722.40824842453
98:fail:722.0141706466675
99:fail:721.6389377117157
```

But with 2nd option. the error happen. when i go to "http://example.org/check" it give difference result each time.

some time is below:

```
0:fail:780.1568698883057
4:fail:778.6187407970428
6:fail:777.8681375980377
9:fail:776.739280462265
13:fail:775.2384984493256
15:fail:774.4248764514923
19:fail:772.897510766983
22:fail:771.7576985359192
25:fail:770.6321122646332
28:fail:769.4517879486084
31:fail:768.3453030586243
34:fail:767.2020778656006
37:fail:766.0453197956085
40:fail:764.8815402984619
43:fail:763.7402126789093
```

another time is below:

```
2:fail:933.5209627151489
5:fail:932.381462097168
8:fail:931.2705476284027
11:fail:930.1319863796234
14:fail:928.9525971412659
17:fail:927.8257281780243
20:fail:926.6680727005005
23:fail:925.52357172966
26:fail:924.3903162479401
29:fail:923.2299783229828
32:fail:922.1214139461517
35:fail:920.9716517925262
38:fail:919.8139469623566
41:fail:918.6542329788208
44:fail:917.4981758594513
49:fail:915.6011772155762
```

i'm thinking it is threadsafe issue. Could someone advise me.
Thanks

Comment: Depending on your configuration gunicorn and nginx will spread you requests over multiple processes which are separate instances of the application with their own variables. This is why you don't rely on global variables in web applications.

Comment: Hi @KlausD. Do you mean Gunicorn and Nginx make many instances of server_status_dict. That why i got diffrence result on each time request to it?
So how to deal with that? could you advise me.
Thanks